# Chrome Extension - read source code with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I have written code for a small Chrome Extension that scrapes content based on selectors. Once I have the content I need, I push it to my PHP server in order to store it in a database. The code works well except when content is loaded dynamically, I can only see what is visible the source code from the browser.

I thought I could solve the issue by waiting until the page was fully loaded (setInterval) but even when I see that the content is loaded, the source code I'm getting is still the initial one.

I use the following code to create a tab and retrieve the source code:

```
function CreateTab (createProperties)
{
    chrome.tabs.create(createProperties, tab => 
        {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) 
                {
                    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                } 
            else 
                {
                    container = "h2";
                                                    
                    var i = 0;
                    var checkClass = setInterval (function()
                        {
                            if (i<=3)
                                {
                                    console.log('Iteration :'+i);
                                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, 
                                        {
                                            file: 'GetSource.js',
                                        }, async function(results) 
                                        {
                                            let e = chrome.runtime.lastError;
                                            if(e !== undefined)
                                                {
                                                    console.log(tab.id, e);
                                                }
        
                                            // GETTING HTML
                                            parser = new DOMParser();
                                            content = parser.parseFromString(results, "text/html");
                                                
                                            console.log(content);

                                            // CAPTURE TITLES                                                   
                                            try 
                                                {
                                                    datatable = content.querySelectorAll(container);
                                                }
                                            catch(err) 
                                                {
                                                    console.log('Iteration '+i+' table not found');
                                                    datatable = "";
                                                }
                                                                                                                
                                            if (datatable.length>0)
                                                {
                                                    clearInterval(checkClass);
                                                    removeTab(tab.id,3)
                                                                                
                                                    // DATA FOUND!

                                                    i=10;
                                                    }
                                            });
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        clearInterval(checkClass);
                                        console.log('Container not found');
                                        removeTab(tab.id,5)
                                    }   
                                            
                            },10000);
        
                }
                        
        });
            
    
}
```

The script I'm calling to get the source is the following (GetSource.js)

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
var html = '',
    node = document_root.firstChild;
while (node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        html += node.outerHTML;
        break;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        html += node.nodeValue;
        break;
    case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
        html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
        break;
    case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
        html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
        break;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
        // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
        html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
        break;
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
}
return html;
}

sourcecode = DOMtoString (document);
sourcecode
```

How can I make sure that the GetSource.js script is getting the final rendered source code? There are more and more sites using dynamic content loaded after the initial load and with this script I'm stuck on those sites.

There are ready to use scrapers in the Chrome store that can get dynamic content so there must be a solution for my script too. I don't want to use to solutions as I need to retrieve the selectors I want to catch from my server and once the scraping is done pushing them back to the server.

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The proper solution is to use MutationObserver with a callback + *debounce* by say 1000ms so if no mutation occurs within this interval the debounced function will run and signal the loading is done.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I guess this would require a different approach for loading the page? My variable "content" never seems to contain the information I'm looking for so if I use a mutationobserver there, it would not detect changes I assume?

Comment: parser.parseFromString should use `results[0]`.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok but are you sure the dynamic content will be in there? I'm retrieving the content of the dom every XX seconds and checking the content, I don't see the selector I'm looking for. In my understanding the execution of GetSource.js at regular interval would capture all changes but even after 20 seconds, the selector I'm looking for are not yet there while I do see them on the screen of my browser.

Comment: Well, your code was not parsing the results correctly.

Comment: Also inspect the elements in devtools: maybe it's inside an iframe or shadow DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm I adapted the code like suggested (it was working for non dynamic content) but for dynamic content it's still not working. I'm trying to get data out of Google Analytics and there is a table with id #ID-rowTable that I need to retrieve but even after it has completely loaded, the queryselectorall doesn't find it while I can see it in the devtools. From what I see in the devtools, it's indeed an iframe. Is there no way around that?

Comment: Loading the iframe directly doesn't work, Google redirects me to the page I tried to scrape :(

Comment: You can run content script inside the iframe by adding `allFrames: true` to executeScript parameters. The `results` in that case will be an array with each item corresponding to some iframe.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I have tried allFrames: true and also frameID with the right id but when I look at the innerHTML from that iframe it is empty. I have tried to access the iframe from content with iframes = content.querySelectorAll('iframe');

Comment: You probably need to add `matchAboutBlank: true` too.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried but it didn't solve the issue, I'll create a another post specifically to address this issue with iframes because it's too complicated to solve through comments. I'll post the link here. Thanks for your time so far!

Comment: @wOxxOm question with updated code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711063/chrome-extension-how-to-access-iframe-source-code